# Get size of a collection in bytes

Tags: arangodb

Is there a query to get the size in `bytes` of a `collection`? I would like to know how much storage space a certain `collection` needs.

Answer (score 2):

You may call the `collection` api on a single server or a cluster's coordinator like so:

```
<endpoint>/_db/<database>/_api/collection/<collection>/figures
```

In `arangosh` connected to again a single server or cluster's coordinator endpoint

```
> db._useDatabase("<database>");
> db.<collection>.figures();
```